# Flyway: When is repair required for a PostgreSQL database?

Tags: postgresql, flyway

It looks like when a run a migration which fails, that migration is not added to the `schema.version` table but is reflected locally as `pending` state in the `info` command.

Given this, `repair` is not required as there is no checksum stored in `schema.version`.

So I suppose my question is; is there a scenario where repair is required for PostgreSQL and also, what scenario puts a row into `schema_version` that has a non-TRUE value for `success`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct. For PostgreSQL and other databases with DDL transaction support, `success` is always `true`.

The only time repair is required, is when for some reason you had to change a migration and the checksums need to be realigned.